# Transparent div with text on image

Tags: html, css, styles, opacity

I want to accomplish the following effect. ([link](http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/25/76/efc484e23e212576.png))

The idea is that I want a transparent div on the top of the image and in this div i want to place a text with opacity: 1 (non-transparent)

So far I managed to make the div transparent, but all the text in it is also transparent and I don't want that.

Comment: position span or p at the center of image and give some z-index to text your done

Comment: Is that an uncompressed PNG image?  It's taking ages to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you out.

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="images/anyimg.jpg" alt="" />
    <h2>Image text:<br />Image Text</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 span {
    color: white;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}
h2 span.spacer {
    padding: 0 2px;
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.image
{
  position: absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  opacity:.5;

}
.text
{
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity:1;
}
<div>
<img src="image.jpg" class="imgage" />
<span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
```